# In my Möbius transformation, what elements map to what?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Write down the subgroup $M_{\{0, 1 + i, \infty\}} \subset M$ preserving the set $\{0, 1 + i, \infty\}$ together with the explicit isomorphism $S_3$.

I thought the transformation we need is the one mapping $\{0, 1, \infty\}$ to $\{0, 1 + i, \infty\}$ but it's the other way round. How do you know this?

Comment: I guess it is a matter of definition. Where did you get this stuff from? Some book...?

Comment: @DonAntonio It's a question set by my lecturer

Comment: Well, then ask him! Apparently, for him $\,M_{a,b,c}\,$ is the group of Mobius transformations preserving (I suppose this means "fixed points") $\,a,b,c\,$...

Comment: It looks to me as if "preserving" a set must mean mapping that set onto itself, not necessarily fixing each of the points in the set.  That way, any Möbius transformation preserving a set restricts to a permutation of the set; hence the isomorphism [to] $S_3$ mentioned in the question.